# GetModuleFileName Antivirus False Detection ??? Get current process PATH

Tags: c++, windows, api, getmodulefilename

**Hellow I am trying to retrive path off current process...
here is my first code:**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int CALLBACK WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow
)
{
  char loaded_file_name[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, loaded_file_name, MAX_PATH);
    cout<<endl<<loaded_file_name<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");

}
```

**But when I am tring to run it Avira antivir Detects it as : TR/Dropper.Gen :D
I have no Idea why :D
Here is a another code :**

```
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
   int main(int argc,char * argv[])
    {
        cout<<endl
            <<argv[0];  

        system("PAUSE>0");
    }
```

**In that version TR/Dropper.Gen problem is fixed but ...
i wan´t to use WinMain () so there is no argv[0]
Can anyone know another method or function to retrive path ? without conflict with antivirus ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code was fine, you aren't the problem.

## Antivirus software sucks, period.

Comment: @Davit Tvildiani: Exactly, don't worry about it.